# splitting by whitespace and joining with dots creates multiple dots Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string where I want to split in by whitespace. and then join it with a dot. the split works fine but when joining I get additional dots. I know that the log file has tabs but I am splitting by whitespace so not sure the problem. Here it does split fine as you can see it prints @array as *lineswithspacesandtabs*

```
my $line = 'lines with spaces   and     tabs';
@array = split /\s/, $line;
print @array;
```

but now I join them and it does not work

```
$joinedstring = join '.', @array;
print $joinedstring;
```

prints *lines.with.spaces...and.....tabs*

please help.

Comment: Actually if you are replacing the spaces by dot, try the substitution `line=~s/\s+/./g`

Comment: yes thank you. the thing is with my actual script i do more than just search and replace with my split. but you are correct. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there. You are splitting by space `/\s/`, not all whitespace. try split `/\s+/`

```
my $line = 'lines with spaces   and     tabs';
@array = split /\s+/, $line;
```

**EDIT** The default behaviour of split for whitespace is `split " "` instead of `split /\s+/`

```
my $line = 'lines with spaces   and     tabs';
@array = split " ", $line;
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: Any example of `split /\s+/` should almost certainly be written as `split " "`, which is the default behaviour of `split`